# Is there any alternative in Python like Apache Nifi?

Tags: python, apache-nifi, faust

I need to process the data and sent to Faust(streaming) like Nifi is sending data to kafka.

Is there any alternative for Nifi in Python since I can't integrate Faust with Nifi

In nifi I can process and convert csv to json and send to Kafka. Since I am in to python is there any application in Python like Nifi which built in Java. Kafka can also be for streaming and kafka stream api is not there in Python

Comment: From official documentation: "Faust is a stream processing library, porting the ideas from Kafka Streams to Python." Can't understand your goal when Faust is just a library.

Comment: In nifi I can process and convert csv to json and send to Nifi. Since I am in to python is there any application in Python like Nifi which built in Java. Kafka can also be for streaming and kafka stream api is not there in Python as far I know

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no version of NiFi or a comparable dataflow system written in Python.

Comment: If it helps, you can run Jython scripts from NiFi's ExecuteScript processor

Comment: Just incase anyone does stumble upon this thread.  https://github.com/radiantone/pyfi-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no alternative in the Python world to the Apache Nifi. Implementing that is enormous work.

However, if you are willing to roll-up your sleeves and implement something like Nifi, using Faust to do the stream processing is definitely a good idea. You need to implement all other Nifi niceties (GUI for an example) on top of it.